# How to use image src dynamically

Tags: html, css, reactjs, carousel, react-bootstrap

I am trying to import images that are in the src folder but vs code tells me that the names of the files that I am importing are not being used in the code. Does anyone know why?

[import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwXlr.png)

I want the images to be displayed in the carousel without any problem.

Comment: It should be like this src={atlus}. Just remove string.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes it worked like that. I couldn't find how to fix it and in the parts where I looked for myself it didn't come out that way. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome. It’s better if you change this post title to "how to use image src dynamically" for better community help.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much for your help, it really took a headache out of me. I'm going to put it like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that Ashraful Mijan already answered above. I just thought that I would add something. Instead of importing them from your src folder, you could put them in your public folder then you would not need to import them and could just set the path directly in the `img` tag.

For example, if you have your images stored in public/assets, then you could just do this in your carousel.

```
<img src="/assets/image1.jpg" />
```

Comment: Oh! I like that solution too, it simplifies things. Is there another difference between placing my images in public and not in src?

Comment: The main difference is if you place them in public then you do not need to import and just set the img tag src as I described above: <img src="/assets/image1.jpg" />. If you put them in src, then you do need to import them and set the img tag src as the imported img, e.g. <img src={atlus} />

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the extra quote for src

```html
<img src={atlus} />
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Simple and straight to the point, what one often needs.